# How to get annotation field names in when generating code with source_gen

Tags: dart-build

I am trying to implement a generator based on `source_gen`. It will process classes annotated with `ClassAnnotation` and act on fields annotated with various annotations, all of which are subtypes of a 'marker' interface `FieldAnnotationMarker`. Here is an example of 2 such annotations:

```dart
@immutable
@Target({TargetKind.classType})
class ClassAnnotation {
  const ClassAnnotation();
}

abstract class FieldAnnotationMarker {}

@immutable
@Target({TargetKind.field})
class FieldAnnotationA implements FieldAnnotationMarker {
  final String fooString;
  final int barInt;

  const FieldAnnotationA({
    required this.fooString,
    required this.barInt,
  });
}

@immutable
@Target({TargetKind.field})
class FieldAnnotationB implements FieldAnnotationMarker {
  final bool bazBool;

  const FieldAnnotationB({
    required this.bazBool,
  });
}
```

Here is an example annotated class:

```dart
@immutable
@ClassAnnotation()
class Person {
  @FieldAnnotationA(fooString: 'foo', barInt: 17)
  @FieldAnnotationB(bazBool: true)
  final int age;

  const Person({
    required this.age,
  });
}
```

What I need to be able to generate my code is the following information:

- Names of all fields annotated with any subtype of `FieldAnnotationMarker` (here: `age`).
- For each field: a list of the annotations (I need the type, its field names and values in the input source file).

For example, I would be able to generate code like this:

```dart
import 'person.dart';

void function(Person person) {
  // person.age
  final ageAnnotations = [
    const FieldAnnotationA(fooString: 'foo', barInt: 17),
    const FieldAnnotationB(bazBool: true),
  ];

  for (final annotation in ageAnnotations) {
    final processor = annotationProcessors[annotation.runtimeType]!; // annotationProcessors will be imported, is a Map<Type, AnnotationProcessor>
    processor.process(person.age, annotation); // Each processor gets field value and the annotation and knows what to do with this information.
  }

  // Other annotated fields, if exist, according to the pattern.
}
```

Here is my code so far - I can collect the metadata but do so doing some very sketchy things, and it is not very comfortable to use:

```dart
class MyGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<ClassAnnotation> {
  @override
  String? generateForAnnotatedElement(Element element, ConstantReader annotation, BuildStep buildStep) {
    final fieldVisitor = _FieldVisitor();
    element.visitChildren(fieldVisitor);

    print(fieldVisitor.fields); // Will generate code based on collected data.

    return null;
  }
}

class _FieldVisitor extends SimpleElementVisitor<void> {
  final Map<String, List<_Annotation>> fields = {};

  @override
  void visitFieldElement(FieldElement element) {
    final annotations = _fieldAnnotationTypeChecker.annotationsOf(element).map( // <<< 1
      (fieldAnnotation) {
        final typeName = fieldAnnotation.type!.element!.name!;
        final annotationReader = ConstantReader(fieldAnnotation); // <<< 2
        final impl = fieldAnnotation as DartObjectImpl; // <<< 3
        final fields = impl.fields!.map(
          (fieldName, field) {
            return MapEntry(
              fieldName,
              annotationReader.read(fieldName).literalValue, // <<< 4
            );
          },
        );

        return _Annotation(typeName, fields);
      },
    ).toList(growable: false);

    fields[element.name] = annotations;
  }
}

const _fieldAnnotationTypeChecker =
    TypeChecker.fromRuntime(FieldAnnotationMarker);

@immutable
class _Annotation {
  final String typeName;
  final Map<String, Object?> fields;

  const _Annotation(this.typeName, this.fields);
}
```

Here are questions to the lines marked with `<<< <number>`:

1. Here I want to fetch annotations that are subtypes of `FieldAnnotationMarker` - this seems to work for my basic tests but I'm not sure if this is the right way?
2. Is it Ok to just instantiate my own `ConstantReader`?
3. I don't want to hardcode the concrete types into the generator (users are able to register custom annotations and their processors) so I need some way of getting all the fields and values from the annotations dynamically. I can see all I need in the debugger but in code the only way I found to get annotations fields is this cast to `DartObjectImpl` which I detest and which also forces me to import the internal 'analyzer/src'. How can I get the field names in a proper way?
4. This gets me the value like `1` for `int` or `string value` for `String`, but I will need to generate code from this, so I will need to write the string value in quotes eventually. For this I need to transform the value based on the type. Is there a way to get the literals as they appear in code, e.g. the string `true` for bool, `1` for ints and `'string value'` (with the quotes) for strings? This would allow me to just paste this value directly when generating code.

Ideally, I could just get a whole string containing e.g. `FieldAnnotationA(fooString: 'foo', barInt: 17)` instead of having to collect the parts (type name, field names, values) and then join all of it together again - is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here I want to fetch annotations that are subtypes of `FieldAnnotationMarker` - this seems to work for my basic tests but I'm not sure if this is the right way?

Using a `TypeChecker` for annotations will also match subtypes, so that will work and is a decent solution for finding annotations of specific types.

> Is it Ok to just instantiate my own `ConstantReader`?

Absolutely! It's part of `source_gen`'s public API and only a stateless wrapper around the `DartObject` class from the `analyzer` either way.

> How can I get the field names in a proper way?

By loading the type from the `DartObject` and referring to the defining class:

1. Get `fieldAnnotation.type`
2. Check that it's an `InterfaceType`. An `InterfaceType` is the class used for types based on Dart classes (as opposed to a say `DynamicType` for `dynamic` or a `FunctionType` for functions). Since you're using a `TypeChecker` to find matching annotations, you're guaranteed to only get `InterfaceType`s so you might as well cast there.
3. Use `(fieldAnnotation.type as InterfaceType).accessors` to get all getters and setters defined for that type (note that fields implicitly define a getter as well)
4. For each accessor, you can use `accessor.variable.name` to get the name of the field, which you can then look up in the constant reader. Skip accessors where `isSetter` is true (since you only care about getters) or where `isSynthetic` is false (since you want to get getters defined by fields only and don't care about explicit `get` functions defined on a class).

> Is there a way to get the literals as they appear in code, e.g. the string true for `bool`, `1` for `int`s and `'string value'` (with the quotes) for strings?

For everything except strings, you can just use `toString()` to get a valid literal. For strings, you could write something manually:

```dart
String asDartLiteral(String value) {
  final escaped = escapeForDart(value);
  return "'$escaped'";
}

String escapeForDart(String value) {
  return value
      .replaceAll('\\', '\\\\')
      .replaceAll("'", "\\'")
      .replaceAll('\$', '\\\$')
      .replaceAll('\r', '\\r')
      .replaceAll('\n', '\\n');
}
```

Or use a package doing code-generation for you, like `literalString` from `package:code_builder`.

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I also found this in the meantime: FieldElement.metadata gives me a List<ElementAnnotation>, which has a magical toSource() method that gives me a String like '@FieldAnnotationA(...)' already constructed for me, I only need to strip the leading '@'. I think I will try this approach, seems like less work.

Comment: Thank you as well for mentioning code_builder, I wanted to take a look at it anyway once I get to actually generating the code.